# Передача Int массива из C# в Dll на C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, interop

Пытаюсь передать массив Int из C# в C++. Выскакивает ошибка:

> Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена.

```
[DllImport("FindProject.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool Find(int count, [In, Out] int[] first_v, [In, Out] int[] second_v);


int[] fv = new int[Convert.ToInt32(count_rec)];
int[] sv = new int[Convert.ToInt32(count_rec)];

sqlExpression = "SELECT FIRST_VERTEX, SECOND_VERTEX FROM Edges";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows) // проверка на наличие данных
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id_FVvertex = reader.GetInt32(0);
            int id_SVvertex = reader.GetInt32(1);

            fv[i] = id_FVvertex;
            sv[i] = id_SVvertex;

            i++;
        }

        Find(Convert.ToInt32(count_rec), fv, sv);
    }
}
```

Данные для массива я получаю из заброса к базе данных. 
Если явно указывать константное значение для элементов массива, то все работает. 
Подскажите, как исправить данную проблему?

Строка объявления функции в Dll:

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) bool __stdcall Find(int count, int *first_v, int *second_v)
```

Comment: Размер массивов - `count_rec` - он известен заранее (на этапе компиляции)? Или меняется в рантайме?

Comment: Вы указали атрибуты `[In, Out]` - значит вы и в неуправляемый код передаёте данные и обратно их хотите получить, так?

Comment: По поводу размера массивов. Бегло просмотрел [Marshaling Different Types of Arrays](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays) и [Default Marshaling for Arrays](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-arrays). Возможно, нужно явно указать параметры `SizeConst/SizeParamIndex`. Но не уверен, как это сделать, если их размер не известен заранее.

Comment: Отметте вопрос как отвеченый (зеленая галочка, ставится под цифрой рейтинга ответа,  под "3" или "2", или дополните ответы словами так не получается, или уточните вопрос).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В комментарий не влезает моё сообщение, напишу ответом.

Так как строки при интеропе не используются, параметр `CharSet` не нужен. Хотя он ничего и не портит.

Соглашение о вызове по умолчанию равно `CallingConvention.StdCall` - можно не добавлять.

Возвращаемый тип `bool` нужно маршалировать с указанием следующего атрибута:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
```

Массивы следует помечать атрибутом

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
```

В итоге, объявление функции может выглядеть так:

```
[DllImport("FindProject.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool Find(
    int count,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In, Out] int[] first_v,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In, Out] int[] second_v
);
```

Я не уверен, нужно ли массив преобразовывать в указатель типа `IntPtr`. Вроде бы маршалер, когда встречает `int[]`, сам это делает.

Comment: В книге "Программирование на C# 5.0", Иэн Гриффитс, в главе "Интероперабельность" дано хорошее описание взаимодействия управляемого и неуправляемого кода. Жаль, именно про передачу массивов там сказано очень мало.

Answer (score 2):

У вас fv - используется чисто на запись, и нигде на чтение. Вероятнее всего GC его во время вызова - просто убирает как мусор, считая что далее массив не используется (константные значения хранятся в отдельном месте памяти, и их уборщик не убирает). Самым простым решением будет сказать уборщику, что массив вам нужен, до вызова Find (лучше сразу после new)

```
GC.KeepAlive(fv);
GC.KeepAlive(sv);
```

Чуть по сложнее, можно создать ссылку на массив, состояние ссылки Pinned (в англ pining называется) не даёт среде уничтожить обьект.

```
GCHandle myArrayHandle1 = GCHandle.Alloc(fv,GCHandleType.Pinned);
GCHandle myArrayHandle2 = GCHandle.Alloc(sv,GCHandleType.Pinned);
Find(Convert.ToInt32(count_rec), fv, sv);
myArrayHandle1.Free();
myArrayHandle2.Free();
```

Ранее тут был пост

Можно попробовать вариант с открытыми адресами... и дизассемблером на моменте ошибки проследить ссылки.

Обьявим ф-цию

```
[DllImport("FindProject.dll")]
public static extern bool Find(int count, IntPtr first_v, IntPtr second_v);
```

А вызов будет через маршалинг, таким

```
Find(Convert.ToInt32(count_rec),
     Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(fv,0),
     Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(sv,0));
```

До сих пор я считал что с# не умеет передавать масивы в с++. Код верный.

Comment: к сожалению, это не решило проблему

Comment: Вы показали код на стороне с#, возможно так же есть проблема на стороне с++.

Comment: Да вроде P/Invoke умеет автоматически закреплять массивы и маршалить их в указатели: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays Тут в вопросе фраза "*Если явно указывать константное значение для элементов массива, то все работает.*" как бы намекает, что проблема на самом деле не с P/Invoke, а с чем-то другим

Comment: @nick_n_a [Код в DLL](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tm6IwPloTqgbVO3cqfg5z3TMFZcnn7YU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Массив постоянный или временный fv sv? Можно попробовать `GC.KeepAlive(fv) GC.KeepAlive(sv)` - если поможет - тогда проблема что уборщик мусора сносит массивы.

Comment: @nick_n_a нет, проблема не в мусорщике. Мне кажется, проблема в конвертере `.GetInt32(0)`. Возможно он как-то совсем не совместим с Int

Comment: И всётаки попробуйте добавить KeepAlive два штуки, посто  **MSDN.WhiteKnight** навел меня на эту мысль. *Мне кажется, проблема в конвертере* - откройте окно CPU - проверьте.

Comment: Это как `GC.KeepAlive` может привести к утечке? Не верю.

Comment: @АлевтинаМаркина Если код на С++ ваш, можно попытаться его отладить. "Свойства проекта - Отладка - Включить отладку в машинном коде; Средства - Параметры - Отладка - Общие - Снять галку "Включить только мой код". Далее, убедитесь что для DLL подложен актуальный PDB-файл. В этом случае отладчик должен будет вам указать на конкретную строку в С++, на которой выбивает ошибку.

Comment: "*Вероятнее всего GC его во время вызова - просто убирает как мусор*" - если маршаллер корректно закрепляет объект, то сборщик мусора его трогать не должен. Кроме того, пока код не вышел из метода, локальные переменные не должны становится мусором.